# What is the preferred size of a control?

Tags: java, javafx

My first attempt at playing with JavaFX and I'm trying to understand a little bit about layout management. How do we access the preferred size of a control?

In the example below I am attempting to set the maximum width 200 pixels greater than the preferred width. That is, I want to allow the button to grow (up to a maximum) as the width of the frame is increased.

However when I run the code the preferred width is -1, so adding 200 to the preferred width gives a maximum width of 199.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

public class BorderPaneSSCCE extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Button button = new Button( "Button at PreferredSize" );
        button.setMaxWidth( button.getPrefWidth() + 200 );
        System.out.println(button.prefWidth(-1) + " : " + button.getPrefWidth());

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("Width: " + button.getWidth());
            }
        });

        HBox root = new HBox();
        HBox.setHgrow(button, Priority.ALWAYS);
        root.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Java FX");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println(button.prefWidth(-1) + " : " + button.getPrefWidth());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I run the code and click on the button I see: `Width: 139.0`

After I resize the width of the frame so the button is as large as possible and I click on the button I see: `Width: 199.0`

I was hoping to see `Width: 339.0` (ie. 139 + 200)

So, how do we access the preferred size/width of a control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getPrefWidth()` returns the `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` flag (which is -1) by default.

You can use `prefWidth(-1)` to get the internally computed preferred width. However the preferred width will not be calculated until the node is being layed out by the layout pane (HBox in your example). This happens the first time when the stage is shown.

You have multiple options, if you want the maximum width to depend on the preferred width. One is to set the preferred width to a fixed value with `setPrefWidth()` prior to setting the maximum width.

Another is to implement a custom layout algorithm - either on the node or on a layout pane. Here is an example using a custom button.

```
// button whose maxWidth is always prefWidth + 200
Button button = new Button() {
    @Override
    protected double computeMaxWidth(double height)
    {
        return this.prefWidth(height) + 200.0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you saying `prefWidth(-1)` will return `-1` (or some other invalid width) until the screen is rendered?

Comment: The prefWidth(-1) was the method I was looking for. Too bad it doesn't have a value until the Stage is shown :( The override of the `computeMaxWidth(...)` method seems like the better solution for the given example, but I didn't know how to implement that method without the  prefWidth(...) method (+1).

Comment: @JAtkin, Yes, I just changed my SSCCE to display the prefWidth(-1) after the button is created and it displays 0. When I display the width after the show() method it displays 138.238....

Comment: I thought for sure that `prefWidth(-1)` would work. I wonder why it doesn't work...

Comment: @JAtkin as explained in this answer, the preferred width is not calculated until the node is actually laid out (typically on the first frame rendering containing that node). That's because CSS is not applied to it until then (and it can't know its size until CSS has been applied). A hacky way around this is to call `applyCSS()` on the node, then check the preferred size, but this approach is nicer.

Comment: @James_D I got the part about `prefWidth` not working until the scene is displayed, I was just wondering why. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

`-1` is the value of [`Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#USE_COMPUTED_SIZE), which tells the component to figure out it's own best size. This works because every `Node` has a method called `prefWidth(double height)` and it's double `prefHeight(double width)` (the same for min/max size) that layout managers use for calculating the layout of their children. To get the pref size you need to use

```
button.prefWidth([-1 or Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE])
```

([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#prefWidth-double-))

Comment: Thanks, for the input (+1), I missed the `prefWidth()`, method. I looked at all the "getter" methods. Still have Swing in the back of my head. I'll have to be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

`getPrefWidth()` only works **after** the `Node` has been shown / rendered.

You can either show the `Button` first or try to use [`Node.prefWidth(-1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#prefWidth-double-).

Comment: Yes, the prefWidth(-1) works after the Stage has been shown (+1). The getPrefWidth() doesn't seem to work even after the stage is shown.

Comment: @camickr the `Stage` and the `Button` need to be shown before `getPrefWidth()` works.

Comment: I modified my SSCCE to display the `prefWidth(-1)` and the `getPrefWidth()` when the button is created and after the Stage is shown. The value for the `prefWidth(-1)` changes, but the `getPrefWidth()` does not change. This makes sense to me know that I know about the `prefWidth(...)` method. The `getPrefWidth()` will only change if you use the `setPrefWidth(...)` method.